# Hyperledger Fabric SDK location

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In the Hyperledger Fabric architecture where is the SDK hosted?

After pouring through the Fabric guides and documents I still can't find the exact specification of where the SDK for interacting with or deploying chaincode resides in the overall network architecture.

I am curious as if it is a node on the network then I see this as a single point of failure.

Answer (score 1):

So, the SDK is actually the part in the business flow that interacts with the customer, and therefore it can be hosted anywhere.

- It can be a web application that acts as a front end, having the fabric as the back-end
- It can be a phone application that a user has
- It can be even an IoT device on a RaspBerry Pi that simply logs periodically real world data into the blockchain
- It can be a service that interacts with other services inside a data center.

Comment: If I have a distinct SDK application, and the outcome needs to be transmitted to another server (client). 
How can the client ensure that the response has been endorsed by all organizations in the system (a properly committed response instead of a malicious response by a malicious SDK server)?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger client SDK is a component used to interact with Fabric network. It resides outside of the Fabric network but connected with its own Membership Service Provider (MSP) and network connection profiles. The network connection profile provides client applications the information about the target
blockchain network that are necessary for the applications to interact with it.